# Error on setOnClickListener Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I would like to create a button that redirects the webview to a certain page. The error shown is: 'setOnclickListener never used before'. I've tried giving ***import android.view.View.OnClickListener*** and did not work.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import static sitesegundo.site.R.styleable.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //configuração do icone no title bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        // configuração webview
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        // configuracao subtitulo titlebar
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  Adote A4");
        //getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");


    }


    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.adocao);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(Object arg0) {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent viewIntent =
                    new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: All of that button code needs to be inside of a method. Move it to the bottom of `onCreate()`

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm a beginner. @codeMagic

Answer (score 0):

Code outside of the methods is run before `onCreate()` or any other method. So trying to initialize a `View` such as a `Button` this way will result in the `Button` being null and giving you a `NullPointerException`.

Moving this code to the bottom of `onCreate()` should fix your problem. Just make sure it's **after** `setContentView()` as trying to initialize any `View` before that will return null.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //configuração do icone no title bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    // configuração webview
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    // configuracao subtitulo titlebar
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  Adote A4");
    //getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("");

   // LOOK HERE
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.adocao);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(Object arg0) {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent viewIntent =
                new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                        Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });


}
```

I'm not sure if this is your exact error because it doesn't sound right but it definitely is going to cause an error. I think what you are seeing is a compiler warning before even running the program but I'm not positive on that.